# Por que não posso utilizar $this dentro de uma static class?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, objetos, phpmyadmin

Conforme exemplo abaixo, queria saber por que não posso utilizar o `$this`  dentro de uma *static class*?

```
<?php

class A{
     public static function hello(){
        echo 'hello';
    }
}

class B extends A{  
    public function ok(){
        echo 'ok';
    }

    public static function fprint(){
        A::hello();
        $this->ok();
    }   
}

$obj = new B;
$obj->fprint();
?>
```

O problema é no método `fprint`. Eu entendo que um método static pode ser utilizado sem a necessidade de um objeto, mas se eu chamar um objeto, como fiz, o método `fprint` não precisará utilizá-lo para chamar o método `hello`, pois utilizo a classe A para isso, e o `$this` vai servir para chamar o método `ok` com o objeto da instância que eu criei. Não entendo porque isso dá erro.

O erro retornado:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Comment: Por que simplesmente não remove o `static` de `fprint`? A ideia de um método estático é justamente não depender do objeto. Uma vez que você quer usar o objeto, use um método normal de instância.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O `$this` representa a *instância* de uma classe. Você não deve usá-lo para métodos estáticos, simplesmente pelo fato de não existir o conceito de instância nestes. Aliás, a razão de se usar um método estático é a independência de um objeto instanciado.
<sub><sup>(também [mencionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104142/#comment213295_104142) pelo @utluiz quase no mesmo instante em que postei.)</sup></sub>

A pergunta é outra: se você precisa da instância, por que declarar o método com *static*?

Note que assim funciona normalmente. Até passei o *static* para o método de cima para você ver a sintaxe de resolução de escopo `::` que você usou em `B::ok()` em ação (vide nota ao final):

```
<?php

class A{
     public static function hello(){
        echo 'hello';
    }
}

class B extends A{  
    public static function ok(){
        echo 'ok';
    }

    public function fprint(){
        A::hello();
        $this->ok();
    }   
}

$obj = new B;
$obj->fprint();
?>
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/n5ZCPX)**.

Outro exemplo:

```
<?php

class A{
     public static function hello(){
        echo 'hello';
    }
}

class B extends A{  
    public function ok(){
        echo 'ok';
    }

    public static function fprint(){
        A::hello();
        B::ok();
    }   
}

$obj = new B;
$obj->fprint();
?>
```

Veja esta versão no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ouTqjI)**.

Desta forma também está funcionando no IDEONE, pois não estamos mais usando a instância (`$this`), mas sim fazendo uma nova chamada, desta vez estática, ao método `ok()`.

**Nota importante:** no segundo exemplo a chamada estática só vai funcionar sem o método ser estático se o modo [E_STRICT](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.constants.php) não estiver ativo. Isto é uma operação que pode ser permitida para compatibilidade com versões mais velhas do PHP, o inverso não. Numa situação normal, você teria os dois métodos estáticos.

Algumas referências do manual:
[Paamayim Nekudotayim](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)
[Static](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.static.php)
[Classes](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33028/discussion-between-alvaro-oo-and-bacco).

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente não podes usar `$this` diretamente em métodos estáticos, por estes não estarem diretamente ligados a objectos ou instâncias da classe, enquanto os métodos não estáticos referem-se sempre a objectos ou instâncias dessa classe. Em resposta a isto, podes definir o teu método/proriedade como `static` para que possas usá-lo em métodos estáticos.