# PHP Métodos static

Tags: php, static

O PHP me permite ter métodos `static`. Cuja a vantagem é tê-los acessíveis sem a necessidade de instanciar a classe [Documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.static.php).

Porém, se tratando de métodos `static`, eu posso usá-los das duas formas **DENTRO DA PRÓPRIA CLASSE**:

```
class Teste
{
    private static metodoEstatico()
    {
        //código
    }

    public outroMetodo()
    {
        self::metodoEstatico(); 
        $this->metodoEstatico();
    }
}
```

O PHP permite usar métodos estáticos, das duas formas, dentro da própria classe. Existe alguma diferença em performance ou algo relevante para as duas formas de uso estando dentro da própria class?

Comment: Relacioanda: [Por que não posso utilizar $this dentro de uma static class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104142/91)

Comment: Olha, pelo que eu saiba, não há diferença alguma neste exemplo que deu. Apenas se atente ao comentário acima. Se colocar o this dentro do método statico dará erro. isso, que eu saiba, em qualquer linguagem...

Comment: Bom. Neste caso, acho q vou manter o padrão self::nomeMetodo() para métodos estáticos. Assim a leitura de código ficará mais clara.

Comment: @rray Neste caso não faz sentido eu utilizar um método "private static". Porque não poderei usar a principal vantagem dos métodos estáticos, que é utilizá-los sem a instância a uma class. Sendo assim, devo criar métodos "public static" apenas quando não precisar de uma instância a um Objeto. Estou certo?

Comment: Existe diferença, inclusive você pode usar o `parent`. O self faz referencia a classe daquela função. O parent faz referencia a classe pai. O $this, pelo que eu sei, não pode ser usado desta forma. Na questão de desempenho, eu acredito que não é relevante. A relevância se torna ao usar aquilo que é NECESSÁRIO usar. Antes eu tinha uma visão diferente sobre esse assunto de desempenho no php e micro-otimizações. Eu pensava que otimizações deste tipo pudessem fazer diferença no php. Mas não faz.

Comment: Eu estava errado. Pode usar o `$this` também.

Comment: Teria que mudar para `public` se quiser usar o método fora da classe ou dependendo da funcionalidade pode criar uma função simples não precisa associar ela a nenhuma classe. Uma forma de organizar seria criar uma namespace apenas para 'funções soltas'.